# Using result of Elasticsearch aggregation as a filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of events that are grouped by the individual who attended the event and each event is a nested document with a timestamp for when they attended along with other info such as the event name.

The doc source is essentially this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "events" : [
        {
            "name" : "example event", // keyword type
            "eventDatetime" : "2018-02-26 04:02:57" // date type
        },
        {
            "name" : "other example event",
            "eventDatetime" : "2017-01-01 12:00:01"
        },
        {
            "name" : "final example event",
            "eventDatetime" : "2016-06-12 12:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query the search API to answer questions like: "find all the individuals who attended more than 3 events in 2016". Essentially the equivalent of an SQL `having count(*) > 3` clause. The date range of the query is user-defined so pre-computing the fields at index time is a non-starter. We would need to be able to scroll through all the document results. The index size is in the hundreds of millions and so any post-processing at the application layer is not a viable solution.

It would be possible to restructure the document format if necessary to run this query, but any format needs to be grouped by individual since there are other fields in the document we may be querying on at the same time, such as age and other activities with their own timestamps, so making the event itself the main document is not feasible.

Does Elasticsearch have a way to essentially apply a document aggregation as a filter?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for aggregation across documents (i.e, multiple documents per user) something like this should work

```
GET /_search
{
    "_source": false,
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "events",
            "query" : {
                "range" : {
                    "events.eventDatetime" :{
                        "gte": "01/01/2016",
                        "lte": "12/31/2016",
                        "format": "MM/dd/yyyy"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "user_event_count":{
            "terms":{
                "field": "id",
                "min_doc_count":4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if you also want with-in document aggregation you will have to post process on the client side i think